# trailing slash removal redirection not working in .htaccess apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, yii2

I am working on a project in which i have migrated old to new site. SEO is still working for old site so i have written rules in my yii2 application as

```
'rules' => [
                "<year:\d{4}>/<number1:\d{2}>/<number2:\d{2}>/<slug>"=>'video/parse',
```

This yii2 redirection is working fine for URLS not ending in trailing slash. But this rule fails for trailing slash URLs. To cope with this problem I tried to redirect through apache. To do so i write this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Problem1:**
When I hit http://example.org/2017/09/10/slug/ then it is redirected to http://example.org//2017/09/10/slug/ as you can see an additional slash is added after domain name.
**Problem2:**
When I hit https://example.org/2017/09/10/slug/ then it is not redirected anyway.

**Questions:**
1. How do we redirect for trailing slash?
2. How to get the redirection working for https?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`UrlNormalizer`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer) for such redirections:

```
'urlManager' => [
    // ...
    'normalizer' => [
        'class' => yii\web\UrlNormalizer::class,
        // you can use temporary redirection instead of permanent for tests
        // 'action' => UrlNormalizer::ACTION_REDIRECT_TEMPORARY,
    ],
],
```

You can read more about URL normalization in [this guide article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#url-normalization).

Answer (score 0):

The issue you face is that you are actually *not* using a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") as you claim (I assume that, since the `VirtualHost` directive is invalid in there). And because the `RewriteRule` logic works on *absolute* paths when used in the real http server configuration files as opposed to *relative* paths when used in dynamic configuration files. This is documented pretty prominently, actually. That difference in logic results in your capture (which you reuse with the `$1` reference) to contain an actual leading slash.

So all you need to do is to change is your rule to this more robust version:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

That leading `^/?` allows an unmodified rule to be used likewise in both versions of configuration files with identical logic. The reason for that should be clear, I assume.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).